# Laravel Eloquent ORM sync method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Using Eloquent ORM and Laravel 4.2, is it possible to update a User's information as well as the Groups they are related to in a single line?

I can update the user info like so:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->name = "New Name";
$user->save();
```

I can then associate the user to an array of groups like this:

```
$user->groups()->sync(array(1,2,3));
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do the save and sync in one line. Either using a method, or by chaining.  From what I can tell, this does not work:

```
$user->save()->groups()->sync(array(1,2,3));
```

Also, after syncing, do I need to select the model again in order to have the most updated groups?  Meaning, if I call `$user->groups()->sync(array(1,2,3));`, the $user object will still have the original groups in it's `groups` property rather than the new ones that were just synced.

Is there a way to have the $user model populate with the most current groups, or do I have to "get" the model again?

Comment: No, you can't chain, since `save` returns `boolean`. And yes, you have to reload the relation `$model->load('relation');` after `sync`.